# Trouble with getLastCell() and copying non-empty data in Office Scripts

Tags: excel, typescript

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  await context.sync();
  let Source = workbook.getWorksheet("DUMP")
  let Target = workbook.getWorksheet("Database");
     
  let lastRow = Target.getRange("B:B").getUsedRange().getLastCell().getRowIndex() + 1;
  console.log(lastRow);

  // Add 1 to the last row so we start from the next blank.
  lastRow = lastRow + 1

  Target.getProtection().unprotect("SecretPassword");


  Target.getRange("B" + lastRow).copyFrom(Source.getRange("B3:J90"), ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.values, false, false);
  Target.getProtection().protect({}, "SecretPassword");

}
```

need help with this code. for some reason the last row is not being considered correctly.

if possible need some help with updating of the  code so that source B3:J90 will only get the nonempty cells and paste into last row of B to target sheet.

If I manually change lastrow to the number say 244, it does paste it to 244. but with the other code it doesn't put it on 244 it paste it on row 257 then 353. confirmed  b244 to J244 is empty is empty. btw: K244 onward is not. it has formula. there where only 3 rows of data